# Javascript - Pass variable parameters to Function

Tags: javascript, parameters, parameter-passing, optional-parameters

I am looking to be able to create two functions, BaseFunction and CallbackFunction where BaseFunction takes in a variable set of parameters as such:

```
BaseFunction(arg1, arg2, ....)
{
    //Call the Callback function here
}
```

and callback function receives the same parameters back:

```
CallbackFunction(value, arg1, arg2, ...)
{

}
```

How can I pass the parameters from the base function to the callback function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to call a function with an array of parameters.

```
BaseFunction(arg1, arg2, ....)
{
    // converts arguments to real array
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    var value = 2;  // the "value" param of callback
    args.unshift(value); // add value to the array with the others
    CallbackFunction.apply(null, args); // call the function
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/pYUfG/

For more info on the `arguments` value, look at [mozilla's docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments).

Answer (score 2):

to pass arbitrary number of arguments:

```
function BaseFunction() {
     CallbackFunction.apply( {}, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments ) );
}
```

Comment: You can actually just pass `arguments` to `apply` without calling `slice` on it.

Comment: @Rocket that won't necessarily work on all browsers. arguments is an Array-like object, but not an array. for example, firefox prior to version 4 had a bug that is now fixed that did not allow you to pass an arguments object. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=562448

Comment: True, though I'd hope people have the latest versions of their browsers.  The [Mozilla docs page for apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) says you can pass an "array-like" object.  EDIT: Never mind: `"Note: Most browsers, including Chrome 14 and Internet Explorer 9, still do not accept array like objects and will throw an exception."`.

Answer (score 0):

This *kind of* does the trick:

```
BaseFunction(arg1, arg2, ....)
{
  CallbackFunction(value, arguments);
}
```

However `CallbackFunction` needs to accept array:

```
CallbackFunction(value, argsArray)
{
  //...
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's my fallback right now.  I'd prefer to have it done another way if possible.